# Awk for Iteration of Big Data

Tags: awk, iteration, arcgis, bigdata

I have created an awk script which uses a while loop to iterate through a large ascii text file and write its contents at a set increment.  The ascii text file is a DEM file made of usually integers or floating point values.

This script has worked on other large ascii files, but for some files it will write all of the contents to a new file instead of at the set increment.  Any suggestions for making this code more efficient?

```
#!/bin/csh
set Index = 0 
set filename = 320000
set  yorig = -1003
set cellsize = 0.00025
set LineCounter = 0

while($Index <= $filename )
echo $Index
awk -v i="$Index" -v y="$yorig" -v rows="$filename" -v delta="$cellsize" -v    linecount="$LineCounter" 'BEGIN{printf("ncols 136000\nnrows 320000\nxllcorner 122\nyllcorner %.5f\ncellsize 0.00025\nNODATA_value -9999\n", y+rows*delta-(i+1)*delta);}; {if(NR > 6 && NR <= 4000+i) print $0;}' ./Large_ASCII_FIle.txt >!   $Index"_Increment.txt"
@ Index += 4000
end


Input Data looks like the following:
ncols         136000;
nrows         320000;
xllcorner     122;
yllcorner     -1003;
cellsize      0.00025;
NODATA_value  -9999;
707 707 707 706 706 706 706 706 707 706 706 706 706 706 707 707 708 709 710   711 712 712 712 711 711 711 711 711 711 711 711 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 709 709 709 710 710 709 709 709 709 709 709 710 710 710 709 709 709 709 709 709 708 708 707 707 707 706 706 706 705 705 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 700 700 700 700 701 700 701 701 701 700 700 700 700 700 700 700 700

Desired Output Would be:
ncols        136000;
nrows         320000;
xllcorner     122;
yllcorner     -934;
cellsize      0.00025;
NODATA_value  -9999;
707 707 707 706 706 706 706 706 707 706 706 706 706 706 707 707 708 709 710 711 712 712 712 711 711 711 711 711 711 711 711 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 709 709 709 710 710 709 709 709 709 709 709 710 710 710 709 709 709 709 709 709 708 708 707 707 707 706 706 706 705 705 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 704 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 703 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 702 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 701 700 700 700 700 701 700 701 701 701 700 700 700 700 700 700 700 700
```

Comment: That's not an awk script using a while loop, it's a CSH script with a while loop calling awk iteratively. Don't write CSH scripts (google ["CSH why not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)) and don't use shell lops to manipulate text (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do whatever you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your basic intention is to split a large file into several pieces. You can do this with `awk`, like this:

```
awk 'NR % 4000 == 1 { filename = "increment_" NR } NR > 6 { print > filename }'
```

Print the header data after setting the filename.